# Is there closed form solution for this infinite polynomial or high-order polymonial?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots

The equation is as follows
\begin{align}
\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}P(N)x^N=Z,
\end{align}
where $P(N)$'s are real number satisfying $0\leq P(N)\leq 1$.

Another equation is 
\begin{align}
\sum_{N=1}^{\bar N}P(N)x^N=Z,
\end{align}
where $\bar N\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $\bar N \gg 1$ and  $P(N)$'s also satisfy $0\leq P(N)\leq 1$.

Is there a closed-form solution for any of these two equations (assuming that the Z here is always feasible)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the first one is related to the roots of power series. The second one is related to finding the roots of a polynomial. There is no closed form solution in general. For polynomials of order 5 or more, a closed form solution cannot be always found.

Comment: What you have in mind @Farnight, may be what OP had in mind: to find the zeroes of the left-hand side. If so, your remark is very well taken. The other interpretation, which I discuss below, looks a bit more likely to me.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you mean to solve for $x$, in terms of $Z$. But if you call $f(x)$ the function described by the series, you’re just looking for $x=f^{-1}(Z)$, the inverse function. If you’re starting with the series for sine, for instance, the “solution” would be the series for $\arcsin(Z)$. It’s certainly true, if $f^{-1}(Z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty Q_nZ^n$, that there then is a closed-form expression for each $Q_n$ in terms of $P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_n$. It’s a mess, though. Others may be able to give more insight here.